# Why does push_back() cause crash within malloc()'ed data?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, malloc, stdvector

Why does this crash? I did find out malloc() doesnt call constructors, so I called them myself manually, but it still crashes, I do not understand why.

PS. I know std::vector and new[] exists. Do not tell me to use vectors/new[] as an answer.

```
struct MyStruct {
    vector<int> list;
};
void make_crash(){
    MyStruct *array = (MyStruct *)malloc(100*sizeof(MyStruct));
    MyStruct element; // initialize element here since malloc() doesnt do it.
    array[0] = element; // copy, everything should be alright?
    array[0].list.push_back(1337); // nope, BANG!
    // The above line makes these:
    // First-chance exception at 0x7c970441 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xbaadf005.
    // First-chance exception at 0x00401cd0 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xbaadf00d.
    // Unhandled exception at 0x00401cd0 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xbaadf00d.
}
```

Comment: _Why_ would you want to do that?

Comment: @K-ballo, because i am stupid...

Comment: what if i say im also an idiot, do i get extra points? :P

Comment: While misguided, your question is still interesting... I just wonder what would make someone even attempt to do that.

Comment: @K-ballo, why? indeed, indeed... the mysteries of life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign to a `MyStruct`

```
array[0] = element;
```

there is first an attempt to destroy the old members of the struct - but there isn't any, because they were never constructed. Boom!

The easiest way to get a hundred `MyStruct`s is to use another vector

```
vector<MyStruct>  v(100);
```

No need to use `malloc`.

Comment: i think you explained it best: "there is first an attempt to destroy the old members of the struct". i didnt know assignment operator does that too.

Comment: hmm, not sure if that really is the cause of the crash... because it doesnt crash in the assignment operator, but with the push_back() line. am i right?

Comment: The assignment is formally undefined behavior, which in this case probably damages the heap. The next attempt to allocate memory will notice that...

Answer (score 7):

On the line `array[0] = element;` you're invoking the `operator=` of `array[0]`. Since `array[0]` is uninitialized, this is undefined behavior. Calling any method or operator, including `operator=` on an object whose constructor has not been invoked, is undefined behavior.

To fix your issue, you'd either need to use placement new to invoke the constructor of `array[0]` or just use `new` instead of `malloc`. Unless you have a good reason to use `malloc`, the latter is greatly preferable (or even better: use a vector).

Comment: ...and even better is to use `std::vector`. (And I think you mean former.)

Answer (score 4):

That's not how you initialize an element in-place. The (implicitly created) assignment operator (which calls vector's assignment operator) is being called on an object that doesn't exist which is obviously bad news.

You have to use placement new instead:

`new (array) MyStruct;`

For arrays:

`new (array) MyStruct[100];`

Comment: is it possible anyhow to "hack" it to make it work without new[] ? just interested...

Comment: @Rookie Keep in mind that placement new and regular new are two entirely different things. I don't think there's any hack that isn't undefined behavior.

Comment: @Pubby You are using placement new for a single element. While this is enough as long as only the initial element of the array is concerned, as in the OP's example, you may want to mention the "array" version of placement new for completeness: `MyStruct* array = new(memory) MyStruct[100];`

Comment: @Rookie: Why do you insist on breaking the rules of C++? Those rules are what allows you to know that your code works on *other* compilers. If you don't like those rules, C is a perfectly legitimate language to program in. You can't have it both ways. You either code in C or C++.

Comment: @NicolBolas, what rules? isnt it legal to do `MyStruct* array = new(memory) MyStruct[100]` ?

Comment: @Rookie: You asked if it was possible to make it work without the placement new call. That's what I was talking about.

Comment: @NicolBolas, just curious. wondering how these things even work internally. does new[] make some extra memory telling my CPU something that malloc doesnt? and why/what/how to imitate it without new[] ? or new placement? how do i write it in raw binary code for CPU? is it even possible? what exactly is the magic new[] does here?

Answer (score 1):

```
MyStruct *array = (MyStruct *)malloc(100*sizeof(MyStruct));
```

This is where you go wrong.

`array` is not a pointer to one or more `MyStruct` objects, regardless of whatever type you gave it. The return value from `malloc` is a `void*`. The rules of C++ do not allow you to implicitly cast from a `void*` to other types, which is why you had to put that `(MyStruct*)` in there. The need for an explicit cast alone should tell you that you're doing something shady.

The rules of C++ state that if you explicitly cast a `void*` to some `Type*` (outside of certain, special types), this is *only* legal if the `void*` you're doing the cast on was originally a `Type*` that was itself cast into a `void*`. This is not the cause; this `void*` comes from `malloc` and never was a `MyStruct*`. You're lying to the compiler, and therefore provoking undefined behavior. Hence the crashing.

If you want *defined* behavior, then you need to actually use C++, instead of this "I can't believe it's not C++" language you're inventing. For example:

```
void *block = malloc(100 * sizeof(MyStruct));
MyStruct* array = new(block) MyStruct[100];
```

Notice the complete lack of cast operations here.

Of course, deleting this array is a pain:

```
for(int i = 99; i >= 0; --i)
  array[i].~MyStruct();

free(block);
```

Notice that you have to destroy them backwards, in the reverse order that they were constructed in.

---

> wondering how these things even work internally. does new[] make some extra memory telling my CPU something that malloc doesnt? and why/what/how to imitate it without new[] ? or new placement? how do i write it in raw binary code for CPU? is it even possible? what exactly is the magic new[] does here?

All of that is implementation dependent. Exactly what happens, as far as the language is concerned, is clearly defined. Placement new will, among other things, call the constructor for the object. Array placement new will call the constructors for all of the objects in the array, in order from first to last. If one of them throws, then it will call the destructor on any previously constructed objects, then emit the exception.

Exactly what is being done is implementation dependent, no moreso than exactly how inheritance is implemented and so forth. Obviously the compiler emits some code for it, but again, exactly what is emitted is implementation dependent.

How you would "write it in raw binary code for CPU" is not possible, so long as you're actually writing C++. To implement placement new, you would have to be able to call the class's constructor. And... well, that's what placement new is *for*. You're not allowed to get even a member pointer to the constructor (and even if you could, the contents of member pointers are implementation dependent, and they're not always going to be a naked pointer to some assembly function). So there's no way to even identify the constructor code without platform-specific jury-rigging.

You can learn how to do it for a particular system by looking at the generated assembly for a call to placement new. But it would be different on every compiler.

Comment: why need to destroy on reverse order...?

Comment: @Rookie: Because they were constructed in order from first-to-last, and you should always destroy objects in the reverse order they were constructed in. You don't strictly *have to*, but that is the correct way to handle it.