# C++ dynamic allocation program crashes

Tags: c++, malloc

I have a very simple piece of code with 2 structures and one dynamic allocation. The program crashes on the "nume" initialization.

```
typedef struct{
    int key;
    string name;
} TElement;

typedef struct nod {
   int cheie;
   string nume;
   struct nod *stg, *dr;
} NOD;
```

when i try to do this

```
void ABC::inserare_element(TElement e){
    NOD *p, *q;
    int n;
    /* construction nod p*/
    n=sizeof (NOD);
    p=(NOD*)malloc(n);
    p->cheie = e.key;
    p->nume = e.name; // on this line the program crashes
```

Thanks

Comment: This is C++, you should be using `new`.

Comment: [Quite related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857402/why-does-push-back-cause-crash-within-malloced-data/10857432#comment14143202_10857432). Did the `std::string` ever have its constructor run? If not, it doesn't exist and you cannot assign to it as if it did.

Comment: You don't need `typedef` in C++. Just name your structures - `struct NOD {/*..*/};`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`malloc()` will not invoke the constructor of `NOD`, meaning the constructor of `nume` will not have been invoked resulting in an attempt to use `std::string::operator=` on an unconstructed/uninitialized `std::string`: use `new`.

Answer (score 4):

You have a hot mix here of high-level C++ objects, such as `std::string` and C-style memory allocations such as `malloc`. The thing is that C++'s `new` operator not only allocates memory, but also calls constructor of high-level objects. The problem you are facing is that `nume` object of type `std::string` is not initialized properly, thus you run into undefined behavior that leads to a crash. That is because you are lucky. It could have been a lot worse if program was actually working, but producing strange, unexpected results.

To make it work like you want, you can simply use `new` instead of `malloc`. For example:

```
p = new NOD;
```

If it so happens that you really need to use `malloc` or other memory management API that does not care about C++ objects, then you have to call a constructor of `nume` manually, using a placement new. For example:

```
p = (NOD*)malloc(n);
new ((void *)&p->nume) std::string();
```

In case you go that way - don't forget to call destructor as well or you will end up with a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

You should use new instead of malloc. malloc is a C function and it only allocates a chunk of memory. Using new will call the default constructor of your class, and the string constructor will also be called at this moment.